# Twitter Api js login or verify

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I'd like retrieve information of twitter user via javascript

like Facebook i want know if the user is connected or not authorized, and I want use Javascript

i try

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            console.dir(msg)
        }
    })
```

or with `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json`

but i have this error

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?callback=jQuery110206401098493952304_1387581993655&_=1387581993656 400 (Bad Request)
```

How can i do something like 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Where if user is not connected, then popUp twitter, if connetted (or saved in my database) retrieve information

Thanks